# ejabberd - LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, ejabberd

I'm trying to configure an ejabberd installation, using LDAP authentication, but I just can't login, even with the admin user.
This is part of my ejabberd.cfg file:

```
%...
{auth_method, ldap}.
{ldap_servers, ["server2000.tek2000.local"]}.
{ldap_port,389}.
{ldap_uidattr, "uid"}.
{ldap_base, "dc=server2000,dc=tek2000,dc=com"}.
{ldap_rootdn, "tempadm@tek2000.local"}.
{ldap_password, "secret"}.
%...
```

What am I missing?

I must say that, with OpenFire, I can connect using this credentials/configuration.

I'm using Spark as my client application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect that your ldap_rootdn should actually look something like

```
cn=tempadm,dc=server2000,dc=tek2000,dc=com
```

rather than the format you've used there.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it before where you actually must supply the LDAP:// before the actual path... so for this example

```
LDAP://cn=tempadm,dc=server2000,dc=tek2000,dc=com
```

And I've also seen it before where **LDAP** needed to be in all caps. I don't know anything about what you're using, but just in the time I've used LDAP those were a few things I've discovered.